# Rails 4 and jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have to be doing some thing very silly/stupid here. Been hitting my head all day trying to get jQueryUI to run in my Rails 4.2.1 application, and failed for some reason. Doesn't seem like this should be that hard, I must be doing something stupid that I just can't see.

I added this to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/typeahead
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-theme
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_self  
 *= require_tree .
```

Yet when I type in a window say:

```
$('input').draggable()
```

I get back:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('input').draggable()')
```

I can see in my Resources list that the draggable model is loaded. I see that jQuery is loaded, and can run other jQuery functions. I'm doing something stupid I'm sure, please help!!!

Comment: Sorry, got caught up in some things and couldn't take a second look until just now. Please take a look at my updated answer. You're using bootstrap (I'm assuming BS3), so there's a particular way to do things with the gem.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, there's a typo in the `jquery-ui-rails` documentation that tells you to use `jquery_ui`, even though the correct notation is `jquery.ui` (note the dot, not underscore).

Try this in your `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

`application.css`:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

Comment: When I try the dot notation I get this error: Sprockets::FileNotFound 
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'

Answer (score 0):

I ran:

```
bin/rake assets:clobber
```

and everything seemed to work??? Can anyone explain this for the answer vote;-)